# Latent Dirichlet Allocation Solution Example

Tags: lda, topic-modeling

I am trying to learn about Latent Dirichlet Allocation (LDA). I have basic knowledge of machine learning and probability theory and based on this blog post http://goo.gl/ccPvE I was able to develop the intuition behind LDA. However I still haven't got complete understanding of the various calculations that goes in it. I am wondering can someone show me the calculations using a very small corpus (let say of 3-5 sentences and 2-3 topics).

Answer (score 7):

Edwin Chen (who works at Twitter btw) has [an example](http://blog.echen.me/2011/08/22/introduction-to-latent-dirichlet-allocation/) in his blog.  5 sentences, 2 topics:

- I like to eat broccoli and bananas.
- I ate a banana and spinach smoothie for breakfast.
- Chinchillas and kittens are cute.
- My sister adopted a kitten yesterday.
- Look at this cute hamster munching on a piece of broccoli.

Then he does some "calculations"

- Sentences 1 and 2: 100% Topic A
- Sentences 3 and 4: 100% Topic B
- Sentence 5: 60% Topic A, 40% Topic B

And take guesses of the topics:

- Topic A: 30% broccoli, 15% bananas, 10% breakfast, 10% munching, …

  - at which point, you could interpret topic A to be about **food**
- Topic B: 20% chinchillas, 20% kittens, 20% cute, 15% hamster, …

  - at which point, you could interpret topic B to be about **cute animals**

---

Your question is how did he come up with those numbers?  Which words in these sentences carry "information":

- broccoli, bananas, smoothie, breakfast, munching, eat
- chinchilla, kitten, cute, adopted, hampster

Now let's go sentence by sentence getting words from each topic:

- food 3, cute 0  --> **food**
- food 5, cute 0  --> **food**
- food 0, cute 3  --> **cute**
- food 0, cute 2  --> **cute**
- food 2, cute 2  --> 50% **food** + 50% **cute**

So my numbers, differ slightly from Chen's.  Maybe he includes the word "piece" in "piece of broccoli" as counting towards food.

---

We made two calculations in our heads:

- to look at the sentences and come up with 2 topics in the first place.  LDA does this by considering each sentence as a "mixture" of topics and guessing the parameters of each topic.
- to decide which words are important.  LDA uses "term-frequency/inverse-document-frequency" to understand this.

Comment: The question was asking really about the calculations, about which you just say "Then he does some "calculations" - can you explain further please? :)

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables This was like 2 years ago.  I was too lazy to write the [TF-IDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf) calculations nor did I really understand them!

Comment: I understand TFIDF, its not too hard to implement in python. Edwin Chen glosses over lots of details like extracting words using the poisson distribution which are included in that phase :O

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables Can you do me a favor and post a separate question, even if its very similar to this one? It will help me understand **your** specific motivation and it would be good to revisit this topic.

Answer (score 1):

LDA Procedure

Step1: Go through each document and randomly assign each word in the document to one of K topics (K is chosen beforehand)

Step2: This random assignment gives topic representations of all documents and word distributions of all the topics, albeit not very good ones

So, to improve upon them:
For each document d, go through each word w and compute:

- p(topic t | document d): proportion of words in document d that are assigned to topic t
- p(word w| topic t): proportion of assignments to topic t, over all documents d, that come from word w

Step3: Reassign word w a new topic t’, where we choose topic t’ with probability

- p(topic t’ | document d) * p(word w | topic t’)

This generative model predicts the probability that topic t’ generated word w.
we will iterate this last step multiple times for each document in the corpus to get steady-state.

**Solved calculation**

Let's say you have two documents.

Doc i: “T**he bank called about the money.**”

Doc ii: “T**he bank said the money was approved.**”

*After removing the stop words, capitalization, and punctuation.*

Unique words in corpus:
**bank called about money boat approved**
[image]
Next then,

[image]
After then, we will randomly select a word from doc i (word **bank** with topic assignment **1**) and we will remove its assigned topic and we will calculate the probability for its new assignment.

[image]

[image]

For the topic **k=1**
[image]

For the topic **k=2**
[image]

Now we will calculate the product of those two probabilities as given below:
[image]

Good fit for both **document** and **word** for topic 2 (area is **greater**) than topic 1. So, our new assignment for word **bank** will be topic 2.

Now, we will update the count due to new assignment.
[image]

Now we will repeat the same step of reassignment. and iterate through each word of the whole corpus.
[image]